# Test-ModuleManifest error "Remove the elements that are not permitted"

Tags: powershell, module

I am having trouble publishing a module using Powershell 7.3.x to an internal repository. I can import and use the module just fine on my computer. When I attempt to

```
Publish-Module -Path $MySourceDir\my -Repository "MyRepository" -Verbose -Force
```

I get the error

```
Test-ModuleManifest: The module manifest 'my.psm1' could not be processed because it is not a valid PowerShell module manifest file. Remove the elements that are not permitted: my.psd1
```

If we remove

```
RootModule=my.psm1
```

from the my.psd1 file, it passes the test, but the module functions are not exported.
I would love to "Remove the elements that are not permitted" but I have no idea where to begin figuring out what those are. Has anyone else run in to this issue and have a fix or workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this recently using PowerShell 7.3.0.  I can create a blank .psm1 file and a .psd1 having only

```
@{
    RootModule      = 'FakeModule.psm1'
    ModuleVersion   = '0.0.5'
}
```

and get the same error from running Test-ModuleManifest.  I just tried commenting out the RootModule, and sure enough, that allows the test to succeed.

The only way I was able to publish my module was using a Windows PowerShell 5.1 terminal to run the commands.  Not sure if that's an option in your case?